# Custom parameter in Quickblox notification chatroom IOS to android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, notifications, quickblox

Hello everyone i am creating chat application using Quickblox, I have followed the instruction below:

Create APNS certificate and upload it to the Admin panel

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios#Creating_APNS_certificates

Subscribe users to push notifications

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios#Giving_a_user_a_Push_Notification_subscription

I have set the push notification as following way

```
aps =     {

alert = "user one says hi in group";
};
"dialog_id" = 54a3ee0a535c12ea3f01b89f;
"qb_chat_type" = QBGroupChat;
"qb_message_text" = hi;
"qb_message_type" = text;
"qb_sender_image" = "";
"qb_sender_name" = "Neeta khurana";
"tab_group_id" = 200;
"user_id" = 2101266;
}
```

But the quickblox send 2 push notifications in group chat one is above that i have set and another is below:

```
aps =    {
alert = "You have 15 new messages";
sound = 1;
};
"dialog_id" = 54a3ee0a535c12ea3f01b89f;
"user_id" = 2101266;
}
```

So i don't want the notification generated automatically by quickblox and for android device the notification not appears. can anybody help to sort out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this to help others, If any one have this kind of problem then here is the solution. What you have to do go to admin panel in quickblox then go to your application -> Chat -> alert tab you find the following screen. Uncheck the notification for offline users.[image]